# (JS) Поиск текста в теге и его покраска.Либо поиск текста и дополнение своими тегами

Tags: javascript

Заранее прошу простить нуба в JS. Так как знаю что вопрос должен быть очень простой.

Мне нужно по точному тексту в html, на чужом сайте, при помощи кода JS, найти текст и сделать одно из двух.

1. Просто поменять его цвет. ( Цвет в формате "#ff1188" ).
2. Добавить перед ним и после свой тег, что-бы потом за него зацепиться через CSS.

Код оригинала такой:

```
<div class="media-info-list__value text-capitalize">Заморожен</div>
```

Если брать второй вариант решения задачи, то привести код к такому виду.

```
<div class="media-info-list__value text-capitalize"><temp>Заморожен</temp></div>
```

А дальше я уже и сам смогу подцепиться через CSS.
Вся проблема в том, что сайт на разных страницах, в тег div может быть как "Заморожен" так и "Продолжается". И мне нужно выделить "Заморожен" цветом.

Comment: `class="media-info-list__value text-capitalize"` — правильно понимаю, что классы элементов тоже стабильные, нужно просто уметь отличать "заморожен" от "продолжается" ?

Comment: Да. Классы, одинаковые в обоих случаях. Что в случае "заморожен" что в случае "продолжается". И там и там - class="media-info-list__value text-capitalize"

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Находим нужные элементы
let elements = Array.from( document.body.querySelectorAll('*') ).filter( element => element.textContent.trim() === 'Заморожен' );

// Применяем к ним что угодно
elements.forEach( element => {
  element.style.color = 'red';
  element.classList.add('my-super-class');
  element.innerHTML = `<strong>${element.innerHTML}</strong>`;
});
```

```html
<span>Что-то другое</span>
<div class="media-info-list__value text-capitalize">Заморожен</div>
просто слово Заморожен среди текста
<div>Что-то другое</div>
```

Comment: На сайте не дает нужного результата.  
А в консоли вот так ругается

```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined  
    at <anonymous>:2:106
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:2:67
```

Comment: @SPORES: а как Вы парсите чужой сайт?

Comment: @SPORES дайте ссылку на страницу для проверки.

Comment: @UModeL салам ! ты каким браузером пользуешься ?

Comment: Заменил на textContent чтобы различные элементы типа svg поддерживались

Comment: @MaximLensky: Хромом последним 32-бит

Comment: @UModeL да у меня косяк был - Костян помог слава Богу а то напрягало не по детски

Comment: Как добавить больше вариантов для поиска слов в данный скрипт и другие варианты подкрашивания?

Comment: @DrMundo, серьёзно? Во-первых, подумать и написать стили. Во-вторых, тут один участник был 3 года назад, а другой вообще удалён...